# "Operation timed out" when login using php

Tags: php, database, authentication, phpmyadmin, connection-timeout

I'm trying to make a login system using php and phpmyadmin, the code works when I tried it using XAMPP. In XAMPP I can sign up a new user and save it in phpmyadmin, then use the account to login into a certain page in my website. But in my online website, only the sign up function works. A new account register to online phpmyadmin, when i use the account the result is "operation timed out" since the page load too long.

```
Network Error (tcp_error) 

A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"
The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.

For assistance, contact your network support team.
```

I've tried to stop the firewalld but it still "operation time out".
I tried to login without fill the username and password form, but it shows operation timed out not the login empty (my error handler). I change the session.gc_maxlifetime in php.ini to 10800, nothing changed.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Okay, I will try your suggestion and see if it works, thank you @Emma

Comment: Hi @Emma, I just solved my problem after I changed my $dbServername from "localhost" to "0.0.0.0". The "0.0.0.0" is a local address of mysql (port:3306), I get it after checking my port using SSH. My bad, I though it was "localhost" since I can create a table using "localhost" for $dbServername.